# Track Google Analytics Event in applicationWillTerminate

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I want to track when the user closes the app. For this I send an event to google analytics in `applicationWillTerminate`. However this event never reaches the server. However the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/dispatch) states:

> If a user loses network access or quits your app while there are still hits waiting to be dispatched, those hits are persisted in local storage. They will be dispatched the next time your app is running and dispatch is called.

Hence I would assume, that even if it does not manage to dispatch the tracked event in `applicationWillTerminate` it would do so on restart, after some time. Unfortunately it does not.

Next I tried to call `GAI.sharedInstance().dispatch()` to force Google Analytics to dispatch the event, but it also did not.

Do I miss something, or is it simply not possible to track events in `applicationWillTerminate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application terminates, there is simply no time to make a network connection. `applicationWillTerminate` is for frontend uses for most occurrences.

You might store a variable in `UserDefaults` when the application terminates and send the request with the data stored there after the next app launch.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I feared. I had hoped, it might still be enough time :(